# how to start and stop "azure search" through powershell

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I just use the feature "Azure search". its great and running but I want to stop that service but not find the way to stop it and start it back.
so help me to find another way to stop and start "azure search" service.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to stop and start an Azure Search service. If you want to stop being billed temporarily, you need to delete your service. When you re-create your service later, you'll need to re-index your data since Azure Search does not yet support backup/restore.

You can manage your search service manually using the Azure portal, or programmatically using [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-manage-powershell), [Python](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-search/), [.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Search), [Ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/azure_mgmt_search), [node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-arm-search), or [Java](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cazure-mgmt-search).